# vue.js and laravel 5.2, storing data to db

Tags: laravel, vue.js

--EDIT--

This is working code now, use it as working example for your requests, please do comment if any modifications are to be made.

--EDIT--

Im trying to build a simple one pager with contact form for messages.
Im OK with Laravel but new to Vue.js (been working with jQuery before).

I'm having problems saving the data to the database using the code below.

My form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'contact', '@submit.prevent' => 'sendmessage']) !!}
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
    {!! Form::label('name','Name:',['class' => '']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your name', 'v-model' => 'messageData.name']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
    {!! Form::label('mail','E-mail:',['class' => '']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('mail', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your e-mail', 'v-model' => 'messageData.mail']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
    {!! Form::label('phone','Phone:',['class' => '']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your phone number', 'v-model' => 'messageData.phone']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
    {!! Form::label('message','Message:',['class' => '']) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your message', 'v-model' => 'messageData.message']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
    {!! Form::submit('Send message', ['class' => 'btn btn-default form-control bold-black']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Route (not really sure what does this new middleware web does, will appreciate the link):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/contact', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'MessageController@store']);
});
```

Store method in messageController:

```
public function store(MessageRequest $request)
{
    Message::create($request->all());
    $message = "Message sent succesfully.";
    return $message;
}
```

MessageRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'mail' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => '',
        'message' => 'required|min:10',
    ];
}
```

});

And finally the Vue Component:

```
contact: {
    template: '#contact-template',

    data: function() {
        return {
            messageData: {
                name: null,
                mail: null,
                phone: null,
                message: null
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendmessage: function(messageData) {
            this.$http.post('contact', {messageData:messageData})
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('success ');
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
        }
    }
},
```

This is the console log:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/contact 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous function) @ vue-resource.js:1182
Promise @ vue-resource.js:854
module.exports @ vue-resource.js:1150
module.exports @ vue-resource.js:781
(anonymous function) @ vue-resource.js:1213

error
```

I haven't included csrf token anywhere yet so that could be the problem. I'm working actively on this and any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have solved the above problem:
I was not importing `csrf_token` in header, add this to head of your html file:

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also, the `/` route should go to `web` middleware group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::post('/contact', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'MessageController@store']);
});
```

However, it seems I'm not sending any data to post request since whatever I do I get output:

```
{"name":["The name field is required."],"mail":["The mail field is required."],"message":["The message field is required."]}
```

which are my validation rules for the message model.

EDIT2: (this one is final and hope this helps someone as complete working example, what needs to be done is add the errors under the input fields.)

In Vue contact component send method needs to look like this

```
        sendmessage: function(messageData) {
            this.$http.post('contact', {name:this.messageData.name,mail:this.messageData.mail,phone:this.messageData.phone,message:this.messageData.message})
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('success ');
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
        }
```

to make it work with naming in `MessageRequest`.

Comment: instead of `function(){console.log('success')}` what does `function(response){console.log(response)}` say?

Comment: That was my bad, I redirected all errors to `/`. Fixed that and now I'm getting `Class App\Http\Controllers\MessageRequest does not exist` I'll procede myself from here and get back if I stuck, not really good on debbuging JS. Thanks!

Comment: Great, now the error you're looking for will be in your Laravel logs (because it says server error) so this is not a vue issue

Comment: @Jeff I solved most of the problems but I believe that now I'm stuck at Vue not passing data to the post request.

Comment: Change `{messageData:messageData}` to `{messageData:this.messageData}` in your post request and remove `messageData` as an argument from the `sendmessage` method.

Comment: That solved it. I had to change `messageData:this.messageData` to `name:this.messageData.name,....` to make it fit my validation but this did it. I'll update my question with correct code so other have working example and if you wish you can c/p it to your answer so I can upvote it and you get experiance points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as one final tidbit, you don't need to do the `name:this.messageData.name` thing if you did this:

```
sendmessage: function(messageData) {
        this.$http.post('contact', this.messageData)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('success ');
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    console.log('error');
                });
    }
```